# migrating from require to import syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

What is equivalent of

```
const pqr = require('abc').xyz,
```

in import syntax?
The object notation is causing a bit confusion, i know basic like, the equivalent of

```
const pqr = require('abc');
```

will be

```
import pqr from 'abc'
```

Comment: import { xyz as pqr} from 'abc'

Comment: make sure you set `--esModuleInterop` in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

As @arslan2012 commented:

```
import { xyz as pqr } from 'abc';
```